# How Do I Fix a Code Too Large Error for a Java Applet?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, applet, paint, polygon

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
public class ShadowApplet extends Applet
{
    public void paint (Graphics page)
    {
        setBackground (Color.white);
        page.setColor(Color.black);
        int x[]={1,1,4,4};
        int y[]={1,4,1,4};
        page.fillPolygon(x,y,x.length);
    }
}
```

I have to draw a certain complex image with code in the above format except my arrays are hundreds and hundreds of point long and I have tens of polygons. And with the entry of my 26th polygon, my Java applet will no longer compile saying that my code is too large. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the data, save it in a format and then use something like an `InputStream` to read and deal with the data

Comment: @Rogue could you please explain a little bit more? I am kind of new to this...

Comment: Break the functionality down into smaller method calls.  Place your coordinates into multi dimensional arrays and use loops to perform repeated work.  Use classes to represent the individual elements and provide simple "paint" methods to do the work in a self contained environment

Comment: You can only have 64k of bytecode in a method in Java. Move the data out of the method to fields, or to resource files.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, I mean method. If you look at the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3), you'll see that while the code attribute of a method can have a length specified by a 4-byte unsigned integer ("u4" in the spec), the exception table, line number table, local variables table, and other, all use a 2-byte unsigned integer ("u2" in the spec) to specify a program counter. That limits a method to 64k of bytecode. A class has no such limit.

Comment: Also, note the comment on the `end_pc` of the exception table. The compiler probably limits a method to 64k - 1 bytes because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Start by breaking your code down into reusable chunks

For example, you could try keeping your coordinates within one or more, multi-dimensional arrays...

```
int[][] xPoints = {{1,1,4,4}, {...}};
int[][] yPoints = {{1,4,1,4}, {...}};
```

And then use a `for-loop` to paint them...

```
for (int index = 0; index < xPoints.length; index++) {
    int[] x = xPoints[index];
    int[] y = yPoints[index];
    page.fillPolygon(x,y,x.length);
}
```

Now, I don't know about, but this get's really hard to manage as the number of elements increases...

Another idea might be to create a simple "helper" class which focus on managing a single element...

You could start with a simple interface which simply knows how to paint itself, for example...

```
public interface PolyPainter {
    public void paint(Graphics g);
}
```

The create implementations that are self contained portions of the whole...

```
public class PolyHelper implements PolyPainter {
    private int[] xPoints;
    private int[] xPoints;

    public PolyHelper() {
    }

    public PolyHelper(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints) {
        this.xPoints = xPoints;
        this.yPoints = yPoints;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (xPoints != null & yPoints != null) {
            g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints , xPoints.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could either create each instance as you need to...

```
PolyHelper helper = new PolyHelper(new int[]{1,1,4,4}, new int[]{1,4,1,4});
```

Or create specialty classes...

```
public class TopPart extends PolyHelper {
    public TopPart() {
        super(new int[]{1,1,4,4}, new int[]{1,4,1,4});
    }
}
```

In either case, you could then manage these classes in either a `List` or an array...

```
public class ShadowApplet extends Applet
    private List<PolyPainter> polyPainters = new ArrayList<>(25);

    public void init() {
        polyPainers.add(new PolyHelper(new int[]{1,1,4,4}, new int[]{1,4,1,4}));
        polyPainers.add(new TopPart());
        //...
    }
```

Then you would simply need iterate the list to paint them...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    for (PolyPainter painter : polyPainters) {
        painter.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Now having said all that...

I would recommended that:

1. You avoid using `Applet` and start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` instead.  Apart from the fact that top level containers, like `Applet` are not double buffered, using something a `JPanel` as a base not only brings you into a more up-to-date API, but also provides automatic double buffering.  It also de-couples you from a given top level container and makes it easier to re-use the component, as you can then add the `JPanel` to what ever container you want...Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
2. Use the `Shape` (or geometry) API provided by the 2D Graphics API, which does most of what I described in the second half out of the box.  Take a look at [Working with Geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: "Or create specility classes..." Did you mean "specialty" there?